# how Variable assignment work in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
class Node{
    constructor(val) {
        this.val = val;
        this.next = null;
    }
}

class SinglyLingkedList{
    constructor() {
        this.head = null;
        this.tail = null;
        this.length = 0;
    }

    push(val){
        var newNode = new Node(val)
        if (this.head == null) {
            this.head = newNode;
            this.tail = this.head;
        } else{
            this.tail.next = newNode;
            this.tail = newNode;
        }
        
        this.length++;
        return this
    }

    reverse(){
        var node = this.head;
        this.head.next = null;
        this.tail = this.head;
        return node;
    }
}

var list = new SinglyLingkedList()
list.push("1")
list.push("2")
list.push("3")
list.reverse()
```

I'm new at programming. I'm pretty confused with my variable assignment in the reverse method, especially at

```
        var node = this.head;
        this.head.next = null;
        this.tail = this.head;
        return node;
```

Why return node is affected by this.head.next null? is not like what I expected
its return

```
Node : {val: '1', next: null}
```

not

```
Node : {val: '1', next: Node}
```

I wanted to know why it happened?

Comment: `node` and `this.head` are the same object because of `var node = this.head;`.

Comment: Assigning an object doesn't make a copy of it, assigns a reference to the object.

Comment: is it work if the first variable is a number or string? @Barmar

Comment: No, primitive objects are copied.

Comment: They also don't have any properties that you can assign to, so there's no way to tell the difference.

Comment: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#javascript_types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#javascript_types)

Comment: var val = 1;
var node = val;
val = 2
console.log(node); 
is this a different case ?

Comment: because at my main question i assign var newNode = new Node(val), not a primitive object?

Comment: @BagoesHeikhal Your number example from the comment is a different case, because you assign a different value to the variables themselves. In your code example from the question, you assign a new value to the object, while both `node` and `this.head` refer to the same object.

Comment: I kinda get it now thank you @OskarGrosser Barmar Ricky Mo